# How to send css files with express js

Tags: node.js, express

I am having a hard time sending css files with express. The way my project is structured is I have a src folder and inside the src folder is the app.js for the express code as well as another folder titled "public". Inside of this public folder I have an experience.html page as well as an experience.css page. I can only get the html to render on the page and cannot get the css styling to show up. Attached is my code for the app.js page.

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express ();
const port = process.env.Port || 3000;

app.get('/experience', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/experience.html');

})

app.use(express.static('/public/experience.css'))

app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using middleware is enough, you don't need dedicated get routes to the files unless you want to mask some of the filenames.

This should work for your case

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.listen(3000);
```

You can access them on `http://localhost:3000/experience.html, http://localhost:3000/experience.css`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Express static middleware with the path to the **public** folder.

Once you do that, you can expose a route to the files (or) you can access at `localhost:9900`

```js
//Import modules
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

// Define PORT for HTTP Server
const PORT = 9900;

// Initialize Express
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
  console.log(`Your dog server is up and running!`);
});
```